# How can i use dynamic columns on Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

How can i use dynamic columns on Linq?

**For example;**

```
var tmp = (from i in ESE.viw_kisiler
                         where (i.i_want_to_use_dynamic_column_in_here.Contains(kelime))
                         select i);
```

**Other example;**

```
 var a = (ComboBoxItems)ComboBox1.SelectedItem;
    var ColumnName = a.Value;

        var tmp = (from i in ESE.viw_kisiler
                                 where (i.ColumnName.Contains(kelime))
                                 select i);
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: You can't. Linq doesn't support that.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean by dynamic column?

Comment: @Lazarus you can but it takes quite some work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your all replies and comments.

I use a different method;

```
var SQL1 = (from i in ESE.viw_kisiler
                           select i);

                DataTable DT = LINQToDataTable(SQL1);

                var SQL2 = (from t in DT.AsEnumerable()
                         where t.Field<string>(ColumnName).Contains(Word)
                         select t);
```

First of all i was convert Linq Query a DataTable and then i try this codes.
It was working now!

Comment: There was a "case insensitive" about Contains method.
I resolve it via StringComparison and an extension method.

`public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
{
            return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}`

`where t.Field<string>(ColumnName).Contains(Word, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring/4217362#4217362

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2008/02/25/string-contains-really-should-have-an-overload-with-stringcomparison-specified.aspx

Comment: It's a good angle. How does the LINQToDataTable work in this case? Is there any code or library that does this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of dynamic linq library : [Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) or [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

[image]

you can also check : [Dynamic query with Linq](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/04/dynamic-query-with-linq.html)  article on blog.

Comment: I read your wrote. May you look my example. I wanna use .Contains
Thanks.

Comment: @user956872 - i think dynamic linq library easily satify your need

Comment: I saw a lot of examples. But still so methods are very very different.
For exaple its working; _ESE.viw_kisiler.Where(a => a.ad.Contains(kelime))_

But still so i cant use dynamic column name. Thaks.

Comment: Try var tmp = ESE.viw_kisiler.Where(String.Format("{0}.Contains(\"{1}\")", ColumnName , kelime));

Comment: @sgmoore its giving error.

`System.Data.EntitySqlException was unhandled
cannot be resolved into a valid type of function. Near simple identifier.`

Thanks.